# How can I fix the AttributeError: 'NoneType' in the following program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    url = sys.argv[1]
else:
    sys.exit("Error: Enter a TED Talk URL")

r = requests.get(url)
result = ''

print("Gathering Resources...")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

for value in soup.findAll("script"):
    if(re.search("talkPage.init", str(value))) is not None:
        result = str(value)

res_mp4 = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)(mp4)", result).group()
mp4_url = res_mp4.split('"')[0]
print("Downloading video from: "+mp4_url)
file_name = mp4_url.split("/")[len(mp4_url.split("/"))-1].split('?')[0]
print("Storing the video in..."+file_name)

r = requests.get(mp4_url)
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

print("Download Completed")
```

> Running the file "main.py [https://www.ted.com/talks/jia_jiang_what_i_learned_from_100_days_of_rejection"](https://www.ted.com/talks/jia_jiang_what_i_learned_from_100_days_of_rejection%22) causes following error. What causes this?
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\MADAWA\PycharmProjects\TED_Talk_Downloader\main.py", line 23, in 
> res_mp4 = re.search("(?Phttps?://[^\s]+)(mp4)", result).group()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: What do you think happens when `.search()` finds no match? What should happen in that case?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by `re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)(mp4)", result)` returning None. Which means you're calling the group function on None (`None.group()`) causing the NoneType error.

Answer (score 0):

The response is a 404 page meaning the link doesn't exist and thus has no match.

```py
def search(pattern, string, flags=0):
    """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

This is the code of `re`. And since there is no match, it returns `None` which is of `NoneType` and doesn't have the attribute `group`.